# IIS Application Pool ID for storage

Tags: c#, iis

I'm trying to keep app pool CPU usage size in db. There are many app pools and I don't know size which app pool has. I have to do something like this:

> app pool id - cpu usage size in db

but I don't know how to get app pool identity. I have done like this;

```
 var appPoolPath = @"IIS://" + Environment.MachineName + "/W3SVC/AppPools";
                using (var w3svc = new DirectoryEntry(appPoolPath))
                {
                    foreach (DirectoryEntry item in w3svc.Children)
                    {
                        // i can get name like item.Name
                        //but
                        // i need current app pool id in loop
                    }
                }
```

But I've look each app pool have same Guid.  Does not it have to be different?

Comment: Please learn `Microsoft.Web.Administration` API. What you use is obsolete.

Comment: i know this but im working on it i cannot see any identification for appPool.. thanks for your help again :) @LexLi

Answer (score 1):

Install the nuget package [Microsoft.Web.Administration](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Web.Administration/) and iterate like this:

```
var applicationPools = new ServerManager().ApplicationPools;

foreach (var applicationPool in applicationPools )
{
     Console.WriteLine(applicationPool.Name);
     var cpuInfo = applicationPool.Cpu;
     // extract cpu usage
    // get app pool attributes for current app pool
    var attrValue = applicationPool.GetAttributeValue("<attributeNameHere>");
}
```

You may try using [GetAttributeValue()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.administration.configurationelement.getattributevalue(v=vs.90).aspx) method, i am not sure what attribute name you need to use but it could be something like : `ApplicationPoolIdentity`

Also please go through this link it might be useful [Application Pool Identities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities)

Comment: The [ApplicationPool.Cpu property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.administration.applicationpool.cpu(v=vs.90).aspx)  _"gets CPU usage parameters for the current application pool."_

Comment: thank you @ankit_sharma..   it's not what i need. I have to keep App Pool Id in database for that get cpu usage but i don't know app pool's id.. I dont want keep app pool's name in db cause it can't be useful..
I need only Id for appPool.. I hope i can explain it..

Comment: im so confused about making identification on IIS app pool because i dont have server machine which has contains IIS.. thank you anyway :) @ankit_sharma